# Can anyone explain to me what the % really refers to in the Android system, battery usage?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery-life

I am wondering what the different percentages really refer to in the battery usage section. I mean...in total I see more than a 100%. So it is easy to presume that it doest mean a certain percent out of 100%.

Comment: How far it's from 100%? For me it's 102% so I think @Erik might be right that it's just a rounding error.

Answer (score 2):

On my phone (ICS) the apps seem to use less than 100% in total. These must be rounding errors: if you had three apps each using a third of the total, that would be 33.3..% for each one. Android would round this to 33%, so the total would be 3*33%=99%.